# Access vba The project is unviewable

Tags: vba, ms-access, cracking

i have a Access VBA project.
when i open it and check code show."project is unviewable"
Is there any way to release it?
[image]

Comment: There are a number of built-in projects in VBA editor that are unviewable. Are you referring to one of them?

Comment: Is the project in discussion made by you and suddenly started to raise this error when try seeing its code?

Comment: this project is not made by me .The project is not fully Locked and the lib library file be locked.

Comment: What do you mean by "Access VBA project" - is the Access file extension adp or mde or accde? Have you Googled this error message?